# Invalid token does not contain resource_ID (authorizationserverv1.0) PYTHON REQUESTS

Tags: python, api, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to work with an API, I can get the temporary access token by using master credentials but cant access the API, I have tried encoding the token to base64 but I get the same error.

```
import requests
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
client_id='Client ID'
client_secret='Client Secret'
#fetch Temporary access token
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url='https://login.burning-glass.com/v2/oauth/token', client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret)
#get access_token
access_token=token['access_token']

#Access endpoint with temporary token.
headers={'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token}

page = oauth.post('https://apis.burning-glass.com/v2.1/similarity/skills',headers=x)

print page.content
```

I get this API response:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Invalid token does not contain resource id (authorizationserverv1.0)"}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In this case it's probably better to ask the api provider why things are going wrong. They should have clear instructions on how to access their api anyway.

Comment: They gave a documentation it was in cURL. I replicated the exact thing in Python.

Comment: A link to that page perhaps?

Comment: It is a PDF marked as confidential. I will post after asking them.

Comment: That's the full command for curl? Where does the oauth come in?

Comment: I am successful in getting past oauth. I get the access token. But i guess there is a problem with their API

Comment: Go and ask them then. Have you tried using the described approach in curl?

Comment: It worked, had to add these two in headers :  'Content-type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'